# How to update xorriso?

Tags: linux

I am trying to learn more about operating system and am following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/ZiHtuBnVrx4?list=PLHh55M_Kq4OApWScZyPl5HhgsTJS9MZ6M. Everything was going smoothly until the point where I had to use grub-mkresuce to create an iso image to use with a virtual box. I am getting an error saying "your xorriso doesnt support '--grub2-boot-info'. Some features are disabled. Please use xorriso 1.2.9 or later.."

I am left confused and without an iso image. I have looked online for a solution but failed to find any. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Whew lad! I got my answer so I will be going now! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your operating system does not offer a package "xorriso" or "libisoburn",
or if they are older than version 1.2.9 (1.3.0 was released in  2013), then
download and compile GNU xorriso. (MS-Windows users may need Cygwin to get
the necessary compiler and linker tools.)

```
cd ...some.work.directory...
wget https://www.gnu.org/software/xorriso/xorriso-1.5.0.tar.gz
tar xzf xorriso-1.5.0.tar.gz
cd xorriso-1.5.0
./configure && make
```

Check whether the result is willing to work:

```
xorriso/xorriso
```

which should say

```
GNU xorriso 1.5.0 : RockRidge filesystem manipulator, libburnia project.

usage : xorriso/xorriso [commands]
        More is told by command -help
```

You do not need to install it. Rather obtain its absolute address:

```
ls $(pwd)/xorriso/xorriso
```

and use it with the grub-mkrescue option "--xorriso=":

```
grub-mkrescue --xorriso=...absolute.address.of.xorriso...
```

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Thanks dude! That helped a lot!